# How do you compile Halide for iOS?

Tags: ios, halide

The README claims it can compile to armv7, but I cannot find the magic incantation to make it work.

I started down the rabbit hole of changing the Makefile to set the arch=armv7, fixing the resulting compilation errors, etc, but that doesn't seem like the right way to go about it.

There recommended cmake flags are:

```
cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;ARM;NVPTX" -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

But alas, the bin directory contains only a .a and a .so, both of which are compiled for x86_64. There are no dylibs.

I can successfully run the test iOS app in the simulator, linking with the x86 libraries, but I cannot build on a device since there are no arm binaries.

Here is a link to the Halide test app I'm trying to build:
https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/master/apps/HelloiOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AOT compilation for iOS. The JIT in principle works on ARM (the architecture), but not on iOS (the OS).

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: are you trying to build Halide to *run* on ARM, or merely to *generate code* for ARM? (If the latter, any target will do, as all builds of Halide can generate code for all known targets.)

Comment: I was hoping to run Halide on ARM - did I misunderstand the documentation? Is JIT available for ARM, or should I just compile AOT?

Comment: JIT is available for ARM-in-general, but I don't believe we support it on iOS. AOT works quite well for iOS, though.